# Find $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}$ given $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)} = 2$

Tags: calculus, limits

It's assumed that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)} = 2$.

> Find
>   $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}$$

I don't think that it would work out by a random plugging.

Let $f(x) = 2\sin(x).$ 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+3x)}{2\sin(x)} = [\log(1+3x) = 3x + O(x^2)] = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x+O(x^2)}{2\sin(x)} = \frac{3}{2}.$$

But what did I miss? I cannot find a way to prove whether these two limits are connected (or that the result is unique).

Comment: Note that you can write:$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{\sin x} \cdot \frac{\sin x}{f(x)}\ .$$ Is it possible to split the R.H.S as a product of two limits? Why?

Comment: Nitpick.  If $\lim \frac {f(x)}{\sin x}$, I don't think we can say $f$ is "arbitrary".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using these (well-known) limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1,\ \ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

and writing:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+3x)}{f(x)} = 3\lim _{x\to 0} \left[\frac{\ln (1+3x)}{3x}\cdot  \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{f(x)}\right]$$

Can you end it from here?

Comment: What if we happen to have $f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot sin(x) \right) + log(1+3x)$?  Then the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{sin x}$ is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = 2$, but the limit of $\frac{log(1+x)}{f(x)}$ seems to be $\frac{3}{\frac{1}{2} + 3}$ = 6/7.

Comment: @RenEhDaycart $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+3x)}{\sin x} = 3$, not $\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

If the limits exist,

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\log(1+3x)}{\sin(x)}.$$

Comment: I think you forgot a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the last limit.

Comment: @Atticus: no, where would it come from ? But I just noticed a typo, the second expression was the same as the first.

Comment: The limit given as hypothesis is $2$, so it's inverse would be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Atticus: I know but read my identities again.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I read it wrongly.

Comment: @Atticus: no problem.

Answer (score 3):

With  *equivalence of functions near* $0$:

The hypothesis means that $f(x)\sim_0 2\sin x$

On the other hand $\sin x\sim_0 x$ and $\ln(1+x)\sim_0 x$, so
$$\frac{\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}\sim_0 \frac{3x}{2x}=\frac 32.$$

Answer (score 3):

When $f(x) \ne 0; \sin x \ne 0$ we have

$\frac {\log{1+3x}}{f(x)} = \frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}\frac {\sin x}{f(x)}=\frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}\cdot \frac 1{\frac {f(x)}{\sin x}}$

so if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}$ exists than

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{1+3x}}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}\cdot\frac 1{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x)}{\sin x}} = \frac 12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}$

And we can use L'hopital to solve $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{(1+3x)}}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {3\frac 1{1+3x}}{\cos x}= \frac {3\frac 11}{1}=3$

So $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{1+3x}}{f(x)}=\frac 12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}=\frac 32$.

====== old answer =====

You don't let $f(x) = 2\sin x$ but you note that as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{\sin x} = 2$ then for any $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x) = K$ then $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)\frac {f(x)}{\sin x} = 2K$.

So if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\log(1 +3x)}{f(x)}$ exists

then $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\log{(1 +3x)}}{f(x)}= \frac12\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\log{(1 +3x)}}{f(x)}\frac {f(x)}{\sin x}=\frac 12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{(1+3x)}}{\sin x}$

And we can use L'hopital to solve $\frac 12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log{(1+3x)}}{\sin x}=\frac 12\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {3\frac 1{1+3x}}{\cos x}= \frac 12\frac {3\frac 11}{1}=\frac 32$.

I suppose I skirted the issue as to whether it is possible for $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\log(1 +3x)}{f(x)}$ to *NOT* exist.

But it must, as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x}=3$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x)}{\sin x}=2$ *do* exist it must follow that $\frac 32 = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x}}{ \frac{f(x)}{\sin x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}$.

Comment: Regarding the issue of whether it is possible for $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\log(1 +3x)}{f(x)}$ to *NOT* exist *** How do you know that we don't have x arbitrarily close to zero with $f(x)=0$ for those values of x?  If there's no interval around zero with $f(x)$ non-zero for all values x in such an interval, then how can you use the expression $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x}}{ \frac{f(x)}{\sin x}}$?

Comment: A specific example: what if we happen to have the following? 
$f(x) =log(1+3x)$,  if $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x = \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^n$, 
$f(x)=2sin(x)$, otherwise

Comment: If that were so then the limit of $\frac {f(x)}{\sin x}$ couldn't exist. "If there's no interval around zero with f(x) non-zero for all values x in such an interval" That can't be the case as bout $\frac {\log{1+3x}}{\sin x}$ and $\frac{f(x)}{\sin x} $ have limits.

Comment: Thanks!  I have a better challenge: what if we happen to have $f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot sin(x) \right) + log(1+3x)$?  Then the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{sin x}$ is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = 2$, but the limit of $\frac{log(1+x)}{f(x)}$ seems to be $\frac{3}{\frac{1}{2} + 3}$ = 6/7.

Comment: No.  $\lim \frac {\frac 12\sin (x) + \log(1+3x)}{\sin x}=\lim (\frac 12 +\frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x}) = \frac 12 +3 = \frac 72\ne 2$ and so $\lim \frac {\log(1+3x)}{f(x)}=\lim\frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x}\frac {\sin x}{f(x)} = 3*\frac 27 = \frac {6}{7}$

Comment: .... and $\frac {\log(1+3x)}{\frac 12\sin x + \log(1+3x)}$ by L'hopital is $\frac {3}{\frac 12 + 3} = \frac {3}{\frac 72} = \frac 67$.

Comment: $\lim \frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x} \ne \frac 32$.  It equals $3$.  Is only when $\lim \frac {f(x)}{\sin x} = 2$ then $\lim \frac {\log (1+3x)}{f(x)} = \color{red}{\frac 12}\color{green}{\lim \frac {\log(1+3x)}{\sin x}} = \color{red}{\frac 12}\color{green}3 = \frac 32$.

Comment: I tend to make a lot of mistakes when computing.  What if we happen to have, for non-zero x, $f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{x} \cdot log(1+3x) \right) + \left(2 - \frac{3}{x}\right) \cdot sin(x)$?  We seem to get $\frac{f(x)}{sin x}$ equal to 2 as desired, but it doesn't seem obvious that everything else works out.

Comment: @RenEhDaycart The existence of the limit in the hypothesis guarantees that $f(x)\ne 0$ in some neighborhood of $x=0$. Also, in your last example, the limit of $f(x)/\sin(x)$ is not $2$; it's $-2.5$.